# how to create custom rest api for sharepoint 2013 without installing sharepoint 2013

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I need a custom rest api for a sharepoint 2013 online premise site. So, sharepoint isn't installed on my system and its stringent development requirements cannot be fulfilled by my system. So, is there a workaround for creating api for sharepoint without installing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using SharePoint  [CSOM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-net-server-csom-jsom-and-rest-api-index) doesn't require you to have SharePoint Installed.
   You basically need to reference folllowing assemblies in your project and free to go:
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
2. Then I would select to create a standard .NET rest service as separate WebApplication which you can deploy to either separate IIS server in the domain or to the one of SharePoint's farm servers.